# PHP sending different headers on different hosts

Tags: nginx, http-headers, php

I have two identical instances of an application - one on my local machine the other one on a VPS.

The problem ist, that my local instance sends the expected headers:

```
[rico@local]$ curl -I app.local
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.14
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9sh2e9uo9b56sdvhrruakigvd7; path=/
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store, nocache, private
Date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 14:51:30 GMT
Location: /login
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

Whereas the instance on the VPS send some other (wrong) headers:

```
[rico@local]$ curl -I app.vps
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=me5h90pj59g0rh62rjlghtjsi0; path=/
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 14:52:40 GMT
Location: /login
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
```

What / who might be rewriting my headers?

Comment: looks like your vps has different nginx/php cache and/or expire setting. Have you compared them?

Comment: nginx itself can add headers - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Comment: They look the same (to me), I have the following added to the host config of both instances: `expires -1; add_header Cache-Control private;`